# Conditional HttpHandler: how to make certain requests return the default response?

Tags: .net, asp.net, httphandler, ihttphandler

I'm working on an IHttpHandler implementation which will handle all *.gif files. The Handler itself will have code in it to check whether the *.gif files are requested from a certain URL. If this is the case, some customer logic should be performed to put a customer gif in the response.

But I don't know what to do when a regular gif is requested. This should be processed as normal. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you have your generic handler serve only special/dynamic `gif` files which could be requested like that: `myhandler.ashx?file=name` and leave IIS handle normal `.gif` files. Once you associate the ASP.NET runtime with the `.gif` extension in IIS, you will have to implement static files serving which might not be as robust as in IIS.